# iOs - Image scaling and positioning in larger image

Tags: ios, image, scaling

[image]

My question is related to calculating position. Scale the `INNER IMAGE` in `FRONT END` then i need to find the relative position on same in `BACKGROUND PROCESS`. If any one experience in it please share here like an equation or something.

- The `FRONT END` `FRAME IMAGE` have a size of 188x292(WidthxHeight)
  and Larger FRAME IMAGE have the size of 500x750(WidthxHeight).
- `INNER IMAGE` 75x75(WidthxHeight) and Larger `INNER IMAGE`
    199.45x199.45(WidthxHeight)

Question : When i scale the `INNER IMAGE` in `FRONT END`. That is 75x75 to 100x100, then we have the x and y position of that. And i need to calculate the exact position in `BACKGROUND PROCESS`. It's for scale that image programatically.

Comment: do you want relative or exact position?.. please give little more explanation for your issue.

Comment: hope it is relative..

Comment: @SathishKumar yes it is

Answer (score 1):

After INNER IMAGE scale you will have x and y position for it, now convert it to %.

if position of INNER IMAGE is

```
relativeX = (x * 100)/frameImageWidth;
relativeY = (y * 100)/frameImageHeight;
```

position of INNER IMAGE for Background will be

```
x = (relativeX * backgroundFrameImageWidth)/100;
y = (relativeY * backgroundFrameImageHeight)/100;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CGPoint foregroundLocation = CGPointMake(x, y);    
static float xscale = BACKGROUND_IMAGE_WIDTH / FOREGROUND_IMAGE_WIDTH;
static float yscale = BACKGROUND_IMAGE_HEIGHT / FOREGROUND_IMAGE_HEIGHT;
CGPoint backgroundLocation = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(foregroundLocation, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(xscale, yscale));
```